# Creating select list with script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this far with my coding:

```
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(item){
      if (item=="") {
        $(select_element).append($(document.createElement("option")).attr("value",   (item)).html(data[item]));
      } else {
        $(select_element).append($(document.createElement("option")).attr("value",(item)).html(data[item]+" "));
      }
```

'item' is an object with two attributes, description and id. Created select list works basically just find, but it returns the whole object now. Can I modify the createElement function so that id would be the returnable itemValue and description itemLabel? I'm newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the given description of the `item` object, this would be a better approach:

```
$.each(data, function(idx,item) {
    if (!item.id) {
        $(select_element).append($("<option>").attr("value",item.id).html(item.description));
    } else {
        $(select_element).append($("<option>").attr("value",item.id).html(item.description+" "));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, `data` looks like this:

```
[
  {id: 0, description: "label for id 0"},
  {id: 1, description: "label for id 1"},
  {id: 2, description: "label for id 2"},
]
```

Then the following lines should do what you want:

```
$.each(data, function(item){
  if(item.description == "") {
    $(select_element).append($('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.description + '</option>');
  }
  else {
    $(select_element).append($('<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.description + '</option>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try something on the following lines

```
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(item){
      if (item=="") {
        $(select_element).append("<option value='-1'>Empty</option>");
      } else {
        $(select_element).append("<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.description +"</option>");
      }
```

I am not sure what functionality you are looking for when item=""

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
  success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(item){
          if (item=="") {
              $(select_element).append('<option value="">--select--</option>');
          } else {
              $(select_element).append('<option value="' + item.id +'">' + item.description + '</option>');
          }
      }
  }
```